# Sentence Extraction

Tags: algorithm, nlp

Let's say I have the following:

- A list of sentences (with no punctuation)
- A long string of words (with no punctuation)

My goal is to segment this string into chunks of sentences, excluding words that don't form a sentence.

I was going to think of an ad-hoc solution for this, but felt it may be a well-known problem (I mean a problem that it's advisable to implement an efficient existing algorithm, like the shortest path problem, etc...)

So, Are there algorithms for this?

**EDIT:**
Sample sentences:

```
hello

how are you

what do you want

are you hungry

do you want to eat

are you thirsty

do you want to drink

what is your name

good morning

good night
```

Sample input string:

```
do do how are you eat
```

So, `how are you` should be the output.

(The input sample may be strange because it's a speech recognizer output)

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give an example of the data - it's not clear if each line would be considered 1 sentence, for example

Comment: @alex23
What do you mean by constraints? If you mean grammar, I think there isn't.

Comment: Why not compile a regular expression among the sentences, then look for matches in the string? Seems straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few freely available tools discussed here:

http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/7001/the-best-sentence-segmentation-tool-until-now

Comment: They may be expecting punctuation, the first one does.

Comment: Thanks for your response. These may be helpful. But a language-independent tool is preferred, or an algorithm to implement, Since **I am not targeting English**. The samples in my questions are just for the sake of the argument.